# Accessing original decorated function for test purposes

Tags: python, testing, decorator, python-decorators, introspection

I'm using a decorator(`@render_to` from the `django_annoying` package) in a view function.

But the thing is that I wanted to get the original dict that is returned by the view function for test purposes, instead of the `HttpResponse` object that the decorator returns.

The decorator uses `@wraps` (from `functools`).

If there is no way to access this, then do you have any idea of how to test this?

Comment: I removed the `django` tag; this is not specific to Django, really.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wrapped function will be available as a function closure cell. Which cell exactly depends on how many closure variables there are.

For a simple wrapper where the only closure variable is the function-to-wrap, it'll be the first one:

```
wrapped = decorated.func_closure[0].cell_contents
```

but you may have to inspect all `func_closure` values.

Demo using the [`functools.wraps()` example decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def my_decorator(f):
...     @wraps(f)
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
...         print 'Calling decorated function'
...         return f(*args, **kwds)
...     return wrapper
... 
>>> @my_decorator
... def example():
...     """Docstring"""
...     print 'Called example function'
... 
>>> example
<function example at 0x107ddfaa0>
>>> example.func_closure
(<cell at 0x107de3d70: function object at 0x107dc3b18>,)
>>> example.func_closure[0].cell_contents
<function example at 0x107dc3b18>
>>> example()
Calling decorated function
Called example function
>>> example.func_closure[0].cell_contents()
Called example function
```

Looking at the [source code for `@render_to`](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying/blob/master/annoying/decorators.py#L25) you don't have to worry about this though; the wrapped function will be stored in the first closure slot, guaranteed.

If this was Python 3 instead, the wrapped function can be accessed with the `__wrapped__` attribute instead:

```
>>> example.__wrapped__
<function example at 0x103329050>
```

And if you had access to the decorator code itself, you can easily add that same reference in Python 2 code too:

```
def my_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        # implementation

    wrapper.__wrapped__ = f
    return wrapper
```

making introspection just that little bit easier.

Comment: tested here, and it`s working!! thanks for the good and detailed answer =) and for the python 3 info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which recursively searches the original function which is decorated at many levels.
The logic behind this is same as the answer mentioned by @Martin

```
def get_original_decorated_function(deco_func, org_func_name= None):
    if not deco_func.func_closure:
        if deco_func.__name__ == org_func_name:
            return deco_func
        else:
            return None
    for closure in deco_func.func_closure:
        func = closure.cell_contents
        if func.__name__ == org_func_name:
            # This is the original function name
            return func
        else:
            # Recursively call the intermediate function
            return get_original_decorated_function(func, org_func_name)
```